# regex help for replace word with hyperlink

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

i have string like this

```
"this TEST-001 is test TEST-001string TEST-001"
```

So i need to make all the TEST-001 to wrap with hyperlink like

i have tried this but its apply hyperlink to all the matching characters.

```
$re1='(TEST)';  # Word 1
$re2='(-)'; # Any Single Character 1
$re3='(\d+)';   # Integer Number 1

echo preg_replace("/([".$re1.$re2.$re3."])/", "<a href=/$1>$1</a>", $txt);
```

Comment: Remove `[` and `]` and use `$0` instead of `$1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a character class with `[` and `]`, these should be removed. Actually, you are creating too many capture groups, they are all redundant.

You may use this simplified code:

```
$txt = "this TEST-001 is test TEST-001string TEST-001";
$re1='TEST';  # Word 1
$re2='-'; # Any Single Character 1
$re3='\d+';   # Integer Number 1
echo preg_replace("/$re1$re2$re3/", "<a href=/$0>$0</a>", $txt);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/xxGvuD)

Note that the whole match can be backreferenced using the `$0` backreference inside the replacement string, thus, there is no need wrapping the whole pattern with an additional capture group (unlike in Perl older versions where `$&` identical backreference caused performance issues).

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0):

the problem was [. removing them my existing code appear to work like a charm

```
$re1='(TEST)';  # Word 1
$re2='(-)'; # Any Single Character 1
$re3='(\d+)';   # Integer Number 1

echo preg_replace("/(".$re1.$re2.$re3.")/", "<a href=/$1>$1</a>", $txt);
```

Comment: You overload the pattern with capture groups that you do not use. Please see my answer. Besides, you may use string interpolation inside double quoted string literals, that way shortening the code a bit. Also, no need using a capture group around the whole pattern and `$1`, you may use `$0` backreference.